# How to select all entities by a list of relation id's in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I have 2 entities with the following many-to-one relation:

**Child.ts:**

```
@Entity({name: "children"})
export class Child {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    child_id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Parent, parent => parent.children)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "parent_id" })
    parent: Parent;
}
```

**Parent.ts**

```
@Entity({name: "parents"})
export class Parent {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    parent_id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Child, children=> children.parent)
    children: Child[];
}
```

Now, i have a list of parent ids and i want to get all the children of all the parent id's, and i expected the following code to work:

```
const children: Child[] = await this.entityManager.find(Child, {
    where: {
        parent: In([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    }
});
```

How can i do this without joining? and is it possible to do this without query builder?